# Serializing List to JSON in C# creates backslashes in front of quotes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to serialize a List in C# and it is mostly working fine except that it creates backslashes in front of the double quotes.  I have read online that this is a result from serializing the data twice and I have tried different approaches to removing the backslashes but they are not really working for me.

**C# code (Using NewtonSoft.Json Library):**

```
List<string> list_element_object = new List<string>();

foreach (var list_element in total_lists)
{

/* Code to get all of the 'element_lists' data 
Which is eventually used to create the 'columns' data below */ 

var columns = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"@type", "Element_Lists" },
                    {"Name", Element_List_Name },
                    {"Description", Element_List_Description},
                    {"URL", Element_URL }
                };

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(columns);

// Add the serialized object to the list
list_element_object.Add(serialized);

}

// Serlialize the list containing the data and store into a ViewBag variable to use in a View
ViewBag.Element_Data_Raw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list_element_object);
```

**Output:**

```
"{\"@type\":\"Elements\",\"Name\":\"Some_Element_Name\",\"Description\":\"Some_Element_Description\",\"URL\":\"Some_Element_URL\"}"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"{"@type":"Elements","Name":"Some_Element_Name","Description":"Some_Element_Description","URL":"Some_Element_URL"}"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Of course it does. You're serializing a dictionary, adding it to a list (i.e. a list of _strings_) and then serializing that list. If this isn't what you want, you should add `columns` itself (not serialized) to a list and then serialize that list. If you want something else, please can you update your question to reflect what you actually expected to happen.

Comment: @john Is there a more efficient way of achieving this type of serialization without the backslashes in front of the quotes?

Comment: And why do you add the already serialized data to a list and serialize that list again?

Comment: @Jeff: Simply put, don't serialize the dictionary data twice (once by itself, and then once as an item in a list of strings).

Comment: So I originally tried only serializing just the list once but the Json output was just showing List type and not the data itself when I just serialized the List and not the dicitionary as well.

Comment: Can you please show your expected output?

Comment: @john I made an edit above with the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the full output you expect. Like, including the list `[`, `]`, etc.

Comment: the first output, where did you get it? debug? or dump it to response/text file? on debug, all double quotes will be escaped (have slashes).

Comment: @BagusTesa I got the output after putting the Viewbag Variable within my view.  After I inspected my webpage, that is the output that is displayed.

Comment: Jeff, when you added columns to a list, you didn't do `list_element_object.Add(columns.ToString());` did you?

Comment: @John No I did not.  The 'Add' statement is adding the serialized Dictionary item to the list.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking with respect to "So I originally tried only serializing just the list once but the Json output was just showing List type and not the data itself"

Comment: I've added an answer, I'm not 100% sure it is correct since you didn't show the full desired final output, but hopefully it does what you want. I've assumed the quotes you put around the single item output were not part of the desired output (i.e. I'm assuming you actually want _valid_ JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not 100% certain on your question, but this should produce normal JSON output, which I guess is what you want. As noted by Bagus Tesa in the comments, double quotes will be escaped in the debugger display. Since you're double-serializing a dictionary (i.e. first you're serializing it to a string, and then you're serializing that string), you're bound to have escaped strings in your current output.

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list_element_object = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

foreach (var list_element in total_lists)
{

    /* Code to get all of the 'element_lists' data 
    Which is eventually used to create the 'columns' data below */ 

    var Element_List_Name = list_element.Element_List_Name;
    var Element_List_Description = list_element.Element_List_Description;
    var Element_URL = list_element.Element_URL;

    var columns = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        {"@type", "Element_Lists" },
                        {"Name", Element_List_Name },
                        {"Description", Element_List_Description},
                        {"URL", Element_URL }
                    };

    // Add the serialized object to the list
    list_element_object.Add(columns);

}

// Serlialize the list containing the data and store into a ViewBag variable to use in a View
ViewBag.Element_Data_Raw = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list_element_object);
```

Changing the list to store dictionaries, and then serializing only the list will produce JSON like this (I've formatted it for easy viewing):

```
[
  {
    "@type": "Element_Lists",
    "Name": "Some_Element_Name",
    "Description": "Some_Element_Description",
    "URL": "Some_Element_URL"
  }
]
```

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/MPNW8028)

Comment: This answer is perfect and I realize why my error was occurring from my code.  So you were right in that i was serializing my List twice, which resulted in the backslashes in front of the double quotes.  After observing your first line of code, `List<Dictionary<string, string>> list_element_object = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();`, I was able to create a list of Dictionary items and then eventually serialize that list only once.  By using this approach, I only serialized this data once and it didn't create the backslashes.  Thank you!